# open a link in a lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I open a link to view it in a lightbox? Iv tryed from the demo but no luck, any ideas?

**HTML:**

```
<a href="http://rightjs.org/ui/lightbox/demo" rel="lightbox" title="Loaded By Link" onclick="loadLightbox();">click</a>
```

**jQuery:**

```
function loadLightbox(){
    alert( "the link was clicked" );
    Lightbox.load($('http://rightjs.org/ui/lightbox/demo'));
}
```

the link to the live site is [**live**](http://4rtificial.co.za/sandbox/lightbox/)

link to [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruzaki/31k6ktdz/)

link to [**lightbox**](http://rightjs.org/ui/lightbox/demo) that im using.

Comment: Your fiddle shows an error in JS console …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reference right.js as well. See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/31k6ktdz/8/).

```
http://cdn.rightjs.org/right.js
```

Comment: your link works thanks alot, but now whats confusing me is my live link is not working ill update my top code

Comment: @Code try to put your js into **head** element, or at top of your **body** element. I think at the stage where you setting **onclick="loadLightbox();"** your function is not exists yet.

Comment: thanks alot its not working 100% but its good enough thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

i know wysiwygwebbuilder.com can do that.

try

```
displaylightbox('http://google.com',{})
```